# Does fast-eod make difference with LTO tape?

Tags: storage, tape, lto

mt-st has an option:

> fast-eod： space directly to eod (and lose file number)

I run the `eod` operation with/without this option, but is seems no significant difference. Does fast-eod make difference with LTO tape?

My test data:

- HP lto6 tape drive
- write 8GB*312 files (2.5TB), block size 512K, disable compression
- eod without this option from BOT: 4.7s
- eod with this option from BOT: 4s

Answer (score 2):

mt-st `eod` command ultimately sends SCSI `SPACE` command to the drive regardless of `fast-eod` option. According to LTO SCSI [reference](https://render-prd-trops.events.ibm.com/sites/default/files/support/ssg/ssgdocs.nsf/0/4d430d4b4e1f09b18525787300607b1d/%24FILE/LTO%20SCSI%20Reference%20%28EXTERNAL%20-%2020171024%29.pdf), there are two parameters for this operation: CODE and COUNT.

CODE specifies the type of termination point of the operation, as shown below. For example, if CODE=3h, then LTO drive moves the tape forward until reaching EOD.

- 0h : Block
- 1h : Filemarks
- 3h : EOD

COUNT is the number of logical objects to be spaced. This parameter will be ignored if CODE=3h. Even with CODE=0h or 1h, the operation is terminated at the EOD position if the drive encounters EOD while processing the command.

According to Linux tape [driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3df83e164f1f39c614a3f31e39164756945ae2ea/drivers/scsi/st.c), here are the parameters to be used depending on `fast-eod` option:

- Enabled : CODE=3h
- Disabled : CODE=1h and COUNT=8,388,607 (0x7fffff)

Thus, tape drive stops at the EOD potions regardless of Enabled/Disabled. The biggest question is that `CODE=3h` is faster than `CODE=1h and COUNT=8388607`? Here is a direct quote from Bacula [document](https://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/problems/problems/Testing_Your_Tape_Drive.html).

> I just expect, that for older tape drives Filemarks may be slower than End-of-data, but not so much as in Solaris slow mode.